# how to stream webcam on your website

Tags: web, live-streaming

How could I stream my webcam video to my website. Are there any solutions for embeding player to your website? Is there a website that provides webstreaming services and then you just copy html code to your website?

Comment: Did you spend any time looking for answers before asking? What have you found out already? If you haven't looked, _go look_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this before and they have options to generate embed code: http://www.ustream.tv/

Comment: And how exactly did you do it? I signed in but I cant find html code for embeeding... please give me some tips, cuz im so tierd of work and need help

Comment: There is a little 'share' button on the video in your channel once you start a broadcast.  From there you can select 'embed'.